# Sorting out array of postmeta in database

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting

I need to sort out different components of a metadata string in the table postmeta in my WordPress database.

The string looks like this in the database:

> a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:8:"employer";s:15:"ExampleEmployer";s:9:"job_title";s:9:"Job Title";s:4:"date";s:9:"2014-2016";s:5:"notes";s:20:"Experience(job)notes";}}

I got quite worried when I saw this the first time, and tried to search for a more humane row, but couldn't find one, so this is the only one with the information I need.

The information is from a plugin call WP Job Manager, and I haven't found any documentation on how to sort their array out, so I'm asking you kind people.

Thank you!

EDIT: I'm very tired. The string automatically unserializes when fetched from the database, I just saw that now. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: It is a serialized string

Comment: You can unserialize it using unserialize function in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is a serialized String. You have to unserialize the string and fetch the output.

```
<?php  
$serialized_data = serialize(array('Math', 'Language', 'Science'));  
echo  $serialized_data . '<br>';  
// Unserialize the data  
$var1 = unserialize($serialized_data);  
// Show the unserialized data;  
var_dump ($var1);  
?>
```

**Output:**

Serialized:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:4:"Math";i:1;s:8:"Language";i:2;s:7:"Science";}
```

Unserialized:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "Math" [1]=> string(8) "Language" [2]=> string(7) "Science" }
```

Comment: Have u obtained the Output @Grymfogel1 by unserializing the data

Comment: Actually, no. Your example worked perfectly, and I suspect this is the correct answer, but it's returning bool(false). Do I have to return() the value or something? EDIT: It returns bool(false) when I put it into my code.

Comment: This is how I've written the code: `$l_name = get_resume_field("candidate_experience", 3572);

$var1 = unserialize($l_name);

var_dump($var1);`

Comment: Are you getting false as the reply from the var_dump

Comment: Yes, i am. I read about it and it looks like it has to be returned somehow.

Comment: Use `$var1 =unserialize(stripslashes($l_name));` and `var_dump($var1)`

Comment: Didn't do any difference, unfortunately. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122121/discussion-between-naresh-kumar-p-and-grymfogel1).

Comment: Added a solution in chat . have a check at it and let me know if you face any problems again :)